# MDM Development

Tags: java, android, mdm

I am developing the MDM server in java for android devices. I found that we can able to establish communication between server to device with Google Cloud Messaging Server.

Is there any way for server communication to android device in java? Please provide any solution apart from GCM.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own way of doing this. You might look at `MQTT` for this.